# Notification to the parent window from child window in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have problem to release div in parent window. I need to do this: After clicking in box.html, which is opend from index.html , on div id=product1, in parent window (index.html) should be released div id=wProdBox1. How to show jquery/css to do that?

This is index.html

```
<div id="box1">Text</div> 

<div id="wBox1">
  <a href="#" class="hideLink">[X]</a>
  <object id="objPage" name="foo" type="text/html" data="box.html"></object>
</div> 

<div id="wProdBox1">
  <a href="#" class="hideLink">[X]</a>
  <object id="objPage2" name="foo" type="text/html" data="box1.html"></object>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $("#box1").click(function () { 
    $("#wBox1").show("slow"); 
    $("body").addClass("scroll"); 
  });
</script>
```

And this is box.html

```
<div id="product1">Text box</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#product1").click(function () { 
   $("#wProdBox1").show("slow");  //HERE IS PROBLEM
  }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery allows you to pass the window reference after the selector:

```
$("#wProdBox1", window.opener.document).show("slow");
```

I like to simplify this by storing `window.opener.document` in a variable:

```
$( function() {
    var main = window.opener.document;

    $("#product1").click(function () { 
        $("#wProdBox1", main).show("slow");  //HERE IS FIX
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you open box.html as a new window and want to change something in index.html, you have to refer it by `opener`:

```
opener.$("#wProdBox1").show("slow");
```